# CloudQueueMessage QueueTrigger in Azure vs Local Instance

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I need to be able to get to the queue item itself (not the string), so that I can manipulate it from my function.

In run.csx code blelow runs and i get access to `CloudQueueMessage`

```
#r "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage"

using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Queue;
using System;

public static void Run(CloudQueueMessage myQueueItem, ILogger log)
{
            log.LogInformation($"Queue ID: {myQueueItem.Id}");
            log.LogInformation($"Queue Insertion Time: {myQueueItem.InsertionTime}");
            log.LogInformation($"Queue Expiration Time: {myQueueItem.ExpirationTime}");
            log.LogInformation($"Queue Payload: {myQueueItem.AsString}");
}
```

In my local development this code throws an **error**. 
I use all latest Nuget's.

VS2017 15.8.8

Azure Function and Web Job Tools: 15.10.2046.0

```
    using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
    using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
    using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Queue;

    namespace AzurePumps.MyForce
    {
        public static class PersonQueueProcessor
        {
            [FunctionName("PersonQueueProcessor")]
            public static void Run([QueueTrigger("sfcontact-update-error", Connection = "storage-queue-connection")]CloudQueueMessage myQueueItem, ILogger log)
            {
                log.LogInformation($"Queue ID: {myQueueItem.Id}");
                log.LogInformation($"Queue Insertion Time: {myQueueItem.InsertionTime}");
                log.LogInformation($"Queue Expiration Time: {myQueueItem.ExpirationTime}");
                log.LogInformation($"Queue Payload: {myQueueItem.AsString}");
            }
        }
      }
```

Log:

```
Azure Functions Core Tools (2.1.748 Commit hash: 5db20665cf0c11bedaffc96d81c9baef7456acb3)
Function Runtime Version: 2.0.12134.0
Skipping 'SF_SecurityToken' from local settings as it's already defined in current environment variables.
[10/26/2018 8:07:51 PM] Building host: startup suppressed:False, configuration suppressed: False
[10/26/2018 8:07:52 PM] Reading host configuration file 'D:\Projects\Force\bin\Debug\netstandard2.0\host.json'
[10/26/2018 8:07:52 PM] Host configuration file read:
[10/26/2018 8:07:52 PM] {
[10/26/2018 8:07:52 PM]   "version": "2.0"
[10/26/2018 8:07:52 PM] }
[10/26/2018 8:07:53 PM] Initializing Host.
[10/26/2018 8:07:53 PM] Host initialization: ConsecutiveErrors=0, StartupCount=1
[10/26/2018 8:07:53 PM] Starting JobHost
[10/26/2018 8:07:53 PM] Starting Host (HostId=vddk35x1fmsnlt-1608145051, InstanceId=e9842cc2-f4a1-46c2-80d0-3e0aad9ae83b, Version=2.0.12134.0, ProcessId=16720, AppDomainId=1, Debug=False, FunctionsExtensionVersion=)
[10/26/2018 8:07:53 PM] Loading functions metadata
[10/26/2018 8:07:53 PM] 2 functions loaded
[10/26/2018 8:07:54 PM] Generating 2 job function(s)
[10/26/2018 8:07:55 PM] Found the following functions:
[10/26/2018 8:07:55 PM] AzurePumps.MyForce.PersonProcessor.Run
[10/26/2018 8:07:55 PM] AzurePumps.MyForce.PersonQueueProcessor.Run
[10/26/2018 8:07:55 PM]
[10/26/2018 8:07:55 PM] Host initialized (1859ms)
[10/26/2018 8:08:00 PM] Host started (6876ms)
[10/26/2018 8:08:00 PM] Job host started
Hosting environment: Production
Content root path: D:\Projects\Force\bin\Debug\netstandard2.0
Now listening on: http://0.0.0.0:7071
Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
Listening on http://0.0.0.0:7071/
Hit CTRL-C to exit...
[10/26/2018 8:08:06 PM] Host lock lease acquired by instance ID '0000000000000000000000006DB263D8'.
[10/26/2018 8:08:22 PM] Executing 'PersonQueueProcessor' (Reason='New queue message detected on 'sfcontact-update-error'.', Id=1e37d3a4-a992-41c8-b6ca-595787e5224e)
[10/26/2018 8:08:23 PM] Executed 'PersonQueueProcessor' (Failed, Id=1e37d3a4-a992-41c8-b6ca-595787e5224e)
**[10/26/2018 8:08:23 PM] System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function: PersonQueueProcessor. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Exception binding parameter 'myQueueItem'. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage: Binding parameters to complex objects (such as 'CloudQueueMessage') uses Json.NET serialization.
1. Bind the parameter type as 'string' instead of 'CloudQueueMessage' to get the raw values and avoid JSON deserialization, or
2. Change the queue payload to be valid json. The JSON parser failed: Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: i. Path '', line 0, position 0.**
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you don't reference/install `WindowsAzure.Storage` latest version 9.3.2, there seems a bug when integrating with Function SDK. See the [issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/issues/1942#issuecomment-434118970) tracked.

Right now when we create a v2 Function Project, the dependencies in the template, e.g. `Microsoft.NET.SDK.Functions` references `WindowsAzure.Storage` 9.3.1 by default. This version works well(as you have seen in Azure portal), no need to install the package separately.

Besides, recommend you to update `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage` to 3.0.1 to avoid some first chance exception throwing.

Comment: Jerry, i already have Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage at 3.0.1. problem is that Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage nuget has dependecy on WindowsAzure.Storage (>= 9.3.1) and installs WindowsAzure.Storage 9.3.2 on its own. I cant force it to install WindowsAzure.Storage 9.3.1. Any tips?

Comment: @dotsa Weird, The latest queuetrigger template on my side reference `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storag` 3.0.0 with  9.3.1 `WindowsAzure.Storage` by default. Try to add `<PackageReference Include="WindowsAzure.Storage" Version="9.3.1" />` in your .csproj file. If it doesn't work, try to create a new queuetrigger template to see whether the issue persists.

Comment: Yes, creating a new project does include 9.3.1 in it. My project has a reference to another project that references version 9.3.2 and thus it updates to 9.3.2 second i add a reference to that project.

Comment: @dotsa Glad you found the cause. I am afraid 9.3.2 Storage package can't work with function extensions sdk right now. Did you get everything work as expected using v9.3.1? If so, could you accept the answer to close your question?